# Scope in Rolify to filter out Users with specific roles (Rails 4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, scope, rolify

I am far too new to scopes to figure this out.
I have a list of all users on a page, and I'd like to be able to filter out the list based on role (using a checkbox or link at the top).
I can get this to work with another column in the table (such as location), but I cannot figure out how to do so with roles.

In my model, I have this to make it work for location:

```
scope :location, -> (location) { where("location LIKE ?", "#{location}%") }
```

And then in my controller I have

```
@users = User.location(params[:location]) if params[:location].present?
```

Which then leads to this in my index

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
   <%= link_to "filter by #{user.location}", "https://example.com/users?location=" + user.location %>
<% end %>
```

Of course, switching out with just "role" won't work because Rolify does not keep roles and users in the same table.

I have tried using this in my model

```
scope :role, ->(role) { Role.find_by(name: role.to_s).users }
```

but then I cannot figure out how to make it work in my controller and index page. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'v made it sort of work but adding a scope of 
`scope :has_role, lambda{|role| includes(:roles).where(:roles => { :name => role})}`
and then adding to my controller
`@users = User.has_role('admin') if params[:admin]`
but the problem with this is I need to add all the roles individually to the controller, and that list can be edited by an admin. So how do I tell the controller to find all the roles? I tried 
`@users = User.has_role(Role.name) if params[:roles]`
and several variations of that and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Rolify has a helper method for find users with roles:

`User.with_any_role('your_role_here')`

The above will return an array with all the users with the specified role

Comment: The problem with this is that the Admin can create roles, so I don't have a hard list of role names.

Comment: you can store role symbols created by admins in your database in your Roles models, and use them to grant roles anywhere in your app, then scope when you need using the method I gave you.